# Link/href/url attached to my image is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, href

I'm simply trying to make the images clickable so that when a user clicks on the image, it will bring them to another page. I'm almost 100% positive I have the correct code to do so, but it is not working for some reason.

I looked up how to attach a link to an image and used the code I found, but there is still an error. I don't receive any error messages, its just not functioning as it is supposed to. Perhaps it could be something to do with how I set up my background and its blocking the link?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes matrix-rain {
  0% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  5% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  10% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png");  }
  15% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  20% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  25% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png"); }
  30% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  35% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  40% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png"); }
  45% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  50% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  55% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png"); }
  60% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  65% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  70% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png"); }
  75% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  80% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  85% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png"); }
  90% { background-image: url("matrix-pride.png"); }
  95% { background-image: url("matrix-stripes.png"); }
  100% { background-image: url("matrix-green.png"); }
}

#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  animation: matrix-rain 10s linear infinite;
  text-align: center;
}

#background a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 40%;
}

#background a img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#header {
  font-family: fantasy;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 400%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div id="background">
  <h1 id="header">Pills</h1>

  <a href="google.com"><img src="redpill.png" /></a>
  <a href="youtube.com"><img src="bluepill.png" /></a>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You forgot prefix the domains with https://

Comment: @ManuelMB Thanks for the spot on that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: `<img src="redpill.png"/>` is the image in the same folder as the html file?

Comment: You've set `pointer-events: none` on `#background`. Therefore that element and its children will not accept any mouse input. You need to remove that line of CSS, then your links will work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thankyou for spotting that, it helped me solve the issue

Comment: Glad it helped. I would suggest you delete this question as it was only caused by a misunderstanding of the purpose of that CSS property.

Answer (score 2):

I had set pointer-events: none on #background. Therefore that element and its children wouldn't not accept any mouse input. I simply removed that line of CSS, and the links worked.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```html
<img style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="var url='https://google.com'; window.open(url, '_blank');" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Number 1, put all of your link and script sources in the head section, make sure that your image is linking to the direct url and that the name of your images are the actual names and can be found. Give your background a color as well.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 

     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>order</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <style>
        body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #background {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      pointer-events: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      animation: matrix-rain 10s linear infinite;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #background a {
      display: inline-block;
      max-width: 40%;
    }
    
    #background a img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
    
    #header {
      font-family: fantasy;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 400%;
      margin-top: 50px;
    }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="background">
      <h1 id="header">Pills</h1>
    
      <a href="google.com"><img src="redpill.png" /></a>
      <a href="youtube.com"><img src="bluepill.png" /></a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```